# After SSH execute local script cannot stop in GitHub Actions

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh, github-actions

I execute a local shell script on GitHub Actions. But it cannot stop after executing the script successfully.

I try to add `exit 0` at the end of the script, add `> /dev/null 2>&1` in the command and add `-tt` in the command. Above ways all not working.

The following code is the command in the GitHub actions yml file.

```
ssh server < script/docker_deploy.sh
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: why do you use this syntax ( < )?

Comment: @LeiYang Because the script is local, and the `server` is a remote Linux server.

Comment: but nothing prevents you from **scp** the script to remote first.

Comment: @LeiYang But it dont solve this problem truly. I can even fix it with `nohup xxx &`. I wanna know why it cannot stop.

Comment: so please edit your question, i think the question is just about the `<` operator, nothing with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by redirecting all output:

```
nohup java -jar xxxx.jar > nohup.out 2> nohup.err < /dev/null &
```